# Error con file_get_contents y https

Tags: php

Tengo este código:

```
<?php
@$html = file_get_contents($urlFlujo);

echo $urlFlujo;
var_dump($html);

$lectorHtml = new DOMDocument();
@$lectorHtml->loadHTML($html);
?>
```

El problema es que cuando se trata de una url acortada con `ow.ly` por ejemplo, que luego hace una redirección a una web con `https`, la función `file_get_contents` me devuelve `false`.

¿Hay alguna solución a este error?

Comment: Como consejo... No uses el supresor de errores `@`, además de considerarse una mala práctica, puede dar lugar a otros errores inesperados y te encontrarás con que no tienes información de ningún tipo.

Comment: Oh, ahora entiendo la otra pregunta... Creo que ha llegado la hora de **[pasar a cURL](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php)**.

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto file_get_contents no hace redirecciones. Tienes que añadirle un contexto e indicarselo en el.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array (
        'http' => array (
            'follow_location' => true// follow redirects
        )
    )
);
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.site.net/', false, $context);
```

Basado en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009284/how-do-i-ignore-a-moved-header-with-file-get-contents-in-php)

Enlaces a la documentacion oficial de PHP para:

- [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents)
- [stream_context_create](http://php.net/stream_context_create)

Comment: Y si es con `https` lo añado también en el array??

Comment: Segun la documentacion tanto pata http como para https hay que poner http.

Comment: Me da este error solo cuando se trata de un acortador de url: `failed to open stream: Connection refused`

Comment: Eso es que el sitio web te esta rechazando.